# How do I get FileSystemRights in a certain format?

Tags: powershell, formatting, acl

I wrote a little script to give me the access ACLs of a certain path and all its subdirectories and put it in a .txt, but I need it in another format to create a database with easier visibility and access.

Part of the output looks like this:

```
Fullname S            FileSystemRights S AccessControlType
----------            ------------------ ------------------
C:\temp  ; ReadAndExecute, Synchronize ;             Allow;
```

So what I need the output to look like is something like this:

```
Fullname S FileSystemRights S AccessControlType
---------- ------------------ ------------------
C:\temp  ;   ReadAndExecute ;             Allow;
C:\temp  ;   Synchronize    ;             Allow;
```

As you can see I need the individual rights in individual lines and not stacked together.

What I've done so far looks is the following, maybe it helps (I left out unimportant stuff):

```
(Get-Acl $TestPath).Access |
    Format-Table -AutoSize -HideTableHeaders @{L="Fullname";E={$TestPath}},
        @{L="S";E={";"}}, FileSystemRights,
        @{L="S";E={";"}}, AccessControlType,
        @{L="S";E={";"}}, IdentityReference,
        @{L="S";E={";"}}, IsInherited,
        @{L="S";E={";"}}, InheritanceFlags,
        @{L="S";E={";"}}, PropagationFlags |
    Out-File $Out -Append -Width 500

function RecDirs {
    $d = $Args[0]
    $AktRec++
    $dirs = dir $d | where {$_.PsIsContainer}
    if ($AktRec -lt 3) {
        foreach($di in $dirs) {
            if ($di.FullName -ne $null) {
                (Get-Acl $di.Fullname).Access |
                    Format-Table -AutoSize -HideTableHeaders @{L="Fullname";E={$di.FullName}},
                        @{L="S";E={";"}}, FileSystemRights,
                        @{L="S";E={";"}}, AccessControlType,
                        @{L="S";E={";"}}, IdentityReference,
                        @{L="S";E={";"}}, IsInherited,
                        @{L="S";E={";"}}, InheritanceFlags,
                        @{L="S";E={";"}}, PropagationFlags |
                    Out-File $Out -Append -Width 500
            }
            RecDirs($di.Fullname)
        }
    }
}

RecDirs($TestPath)
```

Comment: Take a look at export-csv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split the `FileSystemRights` property at commas and output one line per element. And you definitely want `Export-Csv` for writing the output file.

```
(Get-Acl $di.Fullname).Access | ForEach-Object {
    foreach ($val in ($_.FileSystemRights -split ', ')) {
        $_ | Select-Object @{n='Fullname';e={$di.FullName}},
            @{n='FileSystemRights';e={$val}}, AccessControlType,
            IdentityReference, IsInherited, InheritanceFlags,
            PropagationFlags
    }
} | Export-Csv $Out -NoType -Append
```